# StringTemplate 4 set condition from java

Tags: java, stringtemplate

How to set ST4 condition from Java?

I have following ST4 template

```
templateExample(param) ::= <<
$if (condition)$
<ul><li>$param$ is true</li></ul>
$else$
<ul><li>$param$ is false</li></ul>
$endif$
>>
```

While the main class is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final STGroup stGroup = new STGroupFile("exampleTemplate.stg", '$', '$');
        stGroup.registerRenderer(String.class, new StringRenderer());

        final ST templateExample = stGroup.getInstanceOf("templateExample");
        templateExample.add("param", "Hello World");
        templateExample.add("condition", true);

        System.out.println(templateExample.render());
    }
```

However when i run the code, following error raised :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no such attribute: condition
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.add(ST.java:226)
    at com.cupidocreative.main.StringTemplateSandboxMain.main(StringTemplateSandboxMain.java:16)
```

How to set the "condition" from my java class?
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363331/stringtemplate-list-of-attributes-defined-for-a-given-template

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
templateExample(condition, param) ::= <<
$if (condition)$
<ul><li>$param$ is true</li></ul>
$else$
<ul><li>$param$ is false</li></ul>
$endif$
>>
```